# Is it possible to make a custom handler for the enter key in a npyscreen Textfield?

Tags: python, handler, enter, npyscreen

I'm trying to build a chat application with npyscreen in Python.
When enter is hit on the *Textfield* widget, nothing happens.
I'd like to make this action send the message to the server.

I've already made it working by using a *MultiLineEdit* widget and overriding its method

```
        def when_value_edited(self):
```

to monitor the text input changes. When a newline character was found in the current input string, it would send the message and clear the field.
The problem I have with this approach is that it is a bit dirty.
Apart from that I also prefer using the *Textfield* widget over the *MultiLineEdit* widget.

I tried to creating a handler in the main form, but the eval_input method is never triggered.

```
class MainWindow(npyscreen.FormBaseNew):
    def create(self):
        new_handlers = {
            # Set ctrl+Q to exit
            "^Q": self.exit_func,
            # Evaluate input on newline or carriage return
            curses.ascii.NL: self.eval_input,
            curses.ascii.CR: self.eval_input
        }
        self.add_handlers(new_handlers)

    def exit_func(self, _input):
        exit(0)

    def eval_input(self, _input):
        print("TRIGGERED")
        self.parentApp.msg = self.widget_input.value
        self.widget_input.value = ""
```

I expect the widget_input.value to change to an empty string, but nothing happens when I hit the enter key when typing in the *Textfield* widget.
The eval_input method is never called, while the exit_func method is called as soon as I press control + q.
Is it possible to do what I want to do, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

self.Textfield.entry_widget.handlers.update({curses.ascii.NL: self.input_send})

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good idea to add explanation as to how your code answers the question.